# How to use paths in Typescript in fs.readFile and other non-import paths

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have the following `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
            "baseUrl": "src", 
            "paths": {
                "app/*": ["src/*"],
            }
            ...
    }
}

And I have the following folder structure

    src/
       content/
           numbers.csv
       long/
           folder/
               path/
                  to/
                     file.ts

And now I want to use `fs.readFileSync` to read `numbers.csv`. But I don't want to do something like `fs.readFileSync(path.normalize(__dirname + '../../../../content/numbers.csv))`. I rather do something like `fs.readFileSync('app/content/numbers.csv')`.

Is this possible in Typescript?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to edit tsconfig for your purpose, i'm pretty sure.

The `tsconfig.json` file is used for transfering(compiling) ts codes to js codes, and the later(js codes) is what is excuted by nodejs. The `paths` option provides infomation about ts files(waiting for compiling) to the ts compiler, which can not decide how to transfer the `fs.readFileSync(YOUR_PATH)` line.

You may use `process.cwd()` or something else to avoid such long paths:

```
const appPath = process.cwd() + '/src/'; // if the script is always excuted in the src directory
// or
const appPath = 'YOUR/DATA/PATH'; // absolute path

fs.readFileSync(appPath + '/content/numbers.csv');
```